# How make Java 8 Nashorn fast?

Tags: java, javascript, performance, nashorn

I'm using Java 8 Nashorn to render [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/) to HTML server side. If I compile and cache and reuse a `CompiledScript`, a certain page takes 5 minutes to render. However, if I instead use `eval`, and cache and reuse the script engine, rendering the same page takes 3 seconds.

Why is `CompiledScript` so slow? (sample code follows)

What's a good approach for running Javascript code in Nashorn, over and over again as quickly as possible? And avoiding compiling the Javascript code more than once?

This is the server side Scala code snippet that calls Nashorn in a way that takes 5 minutes: (when run 200 times; I'm compiling many comments from CommonMark to HTML.) (This code is based on [this blog article](http://blog.javabien.net/2014/02/19/use-nashorn-and-webjars-to-execute-javascript-server-side/).)

```
if (engine == null) {
  val script = scala.io.Source.fromFile("public/res/remarkable.min.js").mkString
  engine = new js.ScriptEngineManager(null).getEngineByName("nashorn")
  compiledScript = engine.asInstanceOf[js.Compilable].compile(s"""
    var global = this;
    $script;
    remarkable = new Remarkable({});
    remarkable.render(__source__);""");
}
engine.put("__source__", "**bold**")
val htmlText = compiledScript.eval()
```

**Edit** Note that the `$script` above is reevaluated 200 times. I did test a version that evaluated it only once, but apparently then I wrote some bug, because the only-once version wasn't faster than 5 minutes, although it should have been one of the fastest ones, [see Halfbit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26577661/694469). Here's the fast version:

```
...
val newCompiledScript = newEngine.asInstanceOf[js.Compilable].compile(s"""
  var global;
  var remarkable;
  if (!remarkable) {
    global = this;
    $script;
    remarkable = new Remarkable({});
  }
  remarkable.render(__source__);""")
...
```

**/Edit**

Whereas this takes 2.7 seconds: (when run 200 times)

```
if (engine == null) {
  engine = new js.ScriptEngineManager(null).getEngineByName("nashorn")
  engine.eval("var global = this;")
  engine.eval(new jio.FileReader("public/res/remarkable.min.js"))
  engine.eval("remarkable = new Remarkable({});")
}
engine.put("source", "**bold**")
val htmlText = engine.eval("remarkable.render(source)")
```

I would actually have guessed that the `CompiledScript` version (the topmost snippet) would have been faster. Anyway, I suppose I'll have to cache the rendered HTML server side.

(Linux Mint 17 & Java 8 u20)

**Update:**

I just noticed that using `invokeFunction` at the end instead of `eval` is almost twice as fast, takes only 1.7 seconds. This is roughly as fast as my Java 7 version that used Javascript code compiled by Rhino to Java bytecode (as a separate and complicated step in the build process). Perhaps this is as fast as it can get?

```
if (engine == null) {
  engine = new js.ScriptEngineManager(null).getEngineByName("nashorn")
  engine.eval("var global = this;")
  engine.eval(new jio.FileReader("public/res/remarkable.min.js"))
  engine.eval("remarkable = new Remarkable({});")
  engine.eval(
    "function renderCommonMark(source) { return remarkable.render(source); }")
}
val htmlText = engine.asInstanceOf[js.Invocable].invokeFunction(
                                       "renderCommonMark", "**bold1**")
```

Comment: I have also found nashorn to be slower than rhino http://softwarecenturion.me/posts/2014-04-07-jdk8-nashorn-performance/. It becomes much faster with warm JIT, but it's unusably slow cold. Also curious if there's anything you can do about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The variant of your code which uses `CompiledScript` seems to re-evaluate `remarkable.min.js` 200 times - while your `eval` based version does this once. This explains the huge difference in runtimes.

With just the `remarkable.render(__source__)` precompiled, the `CompiledScript` based variant is slightly faster than the `eval` and `invokeFunction` based ones (on my machine, Oracle Java 8u25).

Comment: This seems to be the explanation. I did test an alternative that didn't reevaluate `remarkable.min.js` more than once, but found it to also take 5 minutes so I didn't include it in the question. However I must have done some mistake (namely accidentally resetting a variable to null, rather than just declaring it), because now when I again tested a `CompiledScript` that didn't reevaluate `remarkable.min.js`, it is roughly as fast as the fast `eval` version (don't know which one is fastest on my computer).

Comment: I updated the question with the fast `CompiledScript` version — it looks roughly like the version you used I hope? I'm feeling a bit unsure about what variables Nashorn remembers after subsequent `eval` invocations, but apparently it does remember top level variables like `global` and `remarkable`.

Comment: Actually I just precompiled the `remarkable.render(__source__)`. All the top level script variables end up in engine scope and get re-used (and eventually modified) by each `eval`, precompiled or not. (I actually verified that bindings are equal after script execution with eval and precompiled variant.)

Answer (score 2):

CompiledScript has been improved a bit in 8u40. You can download early access download of jdk8u40 @ https://jdk8.java.net/download.html

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question though.